# Migrating Wordpress Site from subdirectory to root. Problems!

Tags: wordpress

I have a new version of my website that I'm ready to golive. This new version is in the /info directory off my root domain...

So my current website resolves to site.com

And my wordpress version which will replace it is at site.com/info

What do I need to do in order to make the switch?

I followed network solutions tech support on the initial attempt, which was to change the "Directory" assignment of www.site.com and site.com so that they both point to htdocs/info.

That worked, however, my site's stylesheet no longer appears to be working, and all my links still have the /info path in them. Do I need to simply do a find/replace on mySQL to fix the paths?

**UPDATE**: *I was able to resolve the issues with this simple find/replace functions on wp_options and wp_posts as shown below*...

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE (
option_value,
'http://www.site.com/info',
'http://www.site.com')

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (
post_content,
'http://www.site.com/info',
'http://www.site.com')

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (
guid,
'http://www.site.com/info',
'http://www.site.com')
```

Finally, to resolve remaining 404 issues, I had to go to Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks and just click "Save Changes" in order to get the permalinks to resolve correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow this: [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)?

If you can't back up, you will have to go to the wp_options table databse with phpmyadmin and fix a few paths, but it can be done without an MySql query. Pages have their URL in the wp_posts table.

Are any URLs hardcoded in theme files? It's best to use blog_info functions, i.e. `<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>` and `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` instead: [Template Tags/bloginfo « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/bloginfo)

And this might be helpful: [Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) allows search and replace with Grep through all posts and pages.

Comment: Also, don't forget to adjust the settings in your wp-config.php file. You'll need to update the database name, database user name and password and host. Usually it's localhost, but some places (eg, media temple) have something different.

Additionally, once you move it, if you're having trouble getting into the back-end (because it's redirecting you to the old URL), clear your cookies and browser cache.

Comment: Thanks songdogtech. I appreciate your quick input and the page you referenced did help me to ultimately resolve the issue using the find/replace functions listed in the edited version of my question.